# JSoup: Difficulty extracting a single element

Tags: java, jsoup

For my college coding project, I am tasked with grabbing the live value of bitcoin from the internet and incorporating it into a mini "bitcoin program." The issue is that I am having difficulty extracting the value of bitcoin from certain websites. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried using different websites, with mixed results.

### Example 1

```
    final String url = "https://www.coindesk.com/price/bitcoin";
    try
    {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        Element ele = doc.select("span.currency-price").first();
        final String words = ele.text();
        System.out.println(words);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

### Example 2

```
    final String url = "https://cointelegraph.com/bitcoin-price-index";
    try
    {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        Element ele = doc.select("div.price-value").first();
        final String words = ele.text();
        System.out.println(words);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Example 1 resulted in a java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mycompany.test.Test.main(Test.java:28)

Example 2 ran without fault.

Comment: Have you tried visiting the URL directly in your browser, and checking what comes back for the `span.currency-price` element?

Comment: `<span class="currency-price" ...` is dynamically generated tag.

Comment: I believe the span.currency-price is dynamic. Currently <span class="currency-price">$10,225.36</span>. The String "$10,225.36" is subject to change I believe.

Comment: Well, obviously it's dynamic.  But if it shows up as `<span class="currency-price">`, maybe you should try `doc.select("span[class=currency-price]")`.

Comment: I received the same NullPointerException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Site `https://www.coindesk.com/price/bitcoin` relies heavily on JavaScript when presenting content. Jsoup can't execute JavaScript. It can only parse raw HTML documents.
To see what Jsoup sees try to visit this page with JavaScript disabled. You'll see the page is missing main content. Alternatively visit this page and press Ctrl+U to check page source before JavaScript modifications.
Using Chrome's debugger (Network tab) you can see it makes additional AJAX requests to get current exchange rates in JSON from this URL: https://production.api.coindesk.com/v1/exchangeRates
Then JavaScript is used to create dynamic HTML elements for this data. It also requests few other URLs to fetch graph data.

Answer (score 0):

Jsoup can not parse this page because of an extra `"</div>"` in the `div` with `react-app` id. you can report a bug like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15813821/jsoup-parsing-invalid-html-with-unclosed-tags)